# How to display a kivy ContextMenu on top of a kivy Graph?

Tags: python, kivy

I am still figuring out kivy, so forgive me if this is a silly question. Essentially, I have an application that uses a graph to show data to the user. In addition, I would like to have an application menu at the top of the window with nested menus. This file does almost everything I want:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
import kivy_garden.contextmenu
import kivy_garden.graph

kv = """
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    id: layout
    AppMenu:
        id: app_menu
        top: root.height
        cancel_handler_widget: layout

        AppMenuTextItem:
            text: "Menu #1"
            ContextMenu:
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #11"
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #12"
        AppMenuTextItem:
            text: "Menu Menu Menu #2"
            ContextMenu:
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #21"
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #22"
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "ItemItemItem #23"
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #24"
                    ContextMenu:
                        ContextMenuTextItem:
                            text: "Item #241"
                        ContextMenuTextItem:
                            text: "Hello, World!"
                            on_release: app.say_hello(self.text)
                        # ...
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #5"
    Graph:
        border_color: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        #background_color: [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1]
"""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Simple app menu example'
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def say_hello(self, text):
        print(text)
        self.root.ids['app_menu'].close_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

You'll notice that when the menus appear, the white graph border covers them. If we uncomment the last line in the kivy builder string and give the graph a gray background color, the graph is drawn on top of the application menu and nothing appears when the menu is opened.

I know that `kivy_garden.graph` is using `Canvas` under the hood to draw itself. So, is there a way for widgets to draw on top of another widget's canvas? I have also tried using spinners and dropdowns to solve this issue, but to no avail.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a result of the order in which children of the layout are drawn. With the `Graph` as the last item in the layout, it gets drawn last, over the menu. Here is a modified version of your `kv` that puts the menu last in the layout:

```
FloatLayout:
    id: layout
    Graph:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: root.height - app_menu.height
        border_color: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        background_color: [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1]
    AppMenu:
        id: app_menu
        top: root.height
        cancel_handler_widget: layout

        AppMenuTextItem:
            text: "Menu #1"
            ContextMenu:
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #11"
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #12"
        AppMenuTextItem:
            text: "Menu Menu Menu #2"
            ContextMenu:
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #21"
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #22"
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "ItemItemItem #23"
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #24"
                    ContextMenu:
                        ContextMenuTextItem:
                            text: "Item #241"
                        ContextMenuTextItem:
                            text: "Hello, World!"
                            on_release: app.say_hello(self.text)
                        # ...
                ContextMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Item #5"
```

I have used `FloatLayout` instead of `BoxLayout` in order to place the `AppMenu` last in the layout, and that required setting the `height` of the `Graph` (the `height` of the `AppMenu` is already fixed).